# javascript stops responding while taking video player current time

Tags: javascript, do-while

```
var startTime = parent.startTime;
var endTime = parent.endTime;
var divID = '#'+parent.divId;
var description = parent.description;

do {
    var currentTime1 = $('video').get(0).currentTime;
    if(currentTime1 >= startTime) {
        console.log('in if');alert('hi');
        parent.$(divID).append(description);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){$('video').get(0).currentTime = $('video').get(0).currentTime + 1; currentTime1 = parseInt($('video').get(0).currentTime); }, 1000);

} while (currentTime1 <= endTime);

parent.$(divID).empty(); console.log('at end');
```

the above code stops responding and debuger shows this line var currentTime1 = $('video').get(0).currentTime;

Comment: Have you looked at the console for any output there when it happens? If so, please post it.

Comment: it means you are entering into an infinite loop. just log the currentTime1 and endTime to see if they are valid time objects

Comment: currentTime is always 0 not incremented and endtime is 15. but script halts in first time on this line  currentTime1 = $('video').get(0).currentTime;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var startTime = parent.startTime;
            var endTime = parent.endTime;
            var divID = '#'+parent.divId;
            var description = parent.description;

            var myVar = setInterval(check,1000);
function check()
        {
            var currentTime1 = parseInt($('video').get(0).currentTime);

            if(currentTime1 >= parent.endTime) 
            { 
                clearInterval(myVar);
                parent.$(divID).empty(); 
            }
           else if(currentTime1 >= parent.startTime) 
            {  
                parent.$(divID).empty();
                parent.$(divID).append(description);                       
            } 
        }
```

this code works without loop construct. setInterval() works for repeating the action again and again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code gets to infinite loop, because of

```
do {
    var currentTime1 = $('video').get(0).currentTime;
} while (currentTime1 <= endTime);
```

It's executed as fast as your browser allows, so it get's stuck, because `setTimeout` will be executed after 1s and your currentTime1 will never change.

Please change logic - [use video events, like `timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate)

Comment: debugger shows script halt at $('video').get(0).currentTime code

Comment: can you please tell why currentTime is not provide updated cueernt time of player everytime i access it

Comment: @arun You execute this `while` like 989213 times, your video times does not updates, because your code is blocking any further execution, browser detects that you will get to infinite loop and terminates it.

Comment: my video starts after 21 seconds. don't know why

Comment: video player adds start time to the player. Why ?